# Want Image and text in horizontal align and align same in the grid

Tags: html, css

```html
<div>
<button style="   padding: 10px 16px 10px 16px;
     vertical-align: middle;  
     margin: auto;
     width: 32%;">
    <img  style=" width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
     vertical-align: middle; " src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="Text" />
    <span>Click to Stage</span>
</button>
<button style="   padding: 10px 16px 10px 16px;
     vertical-align: middle;  
     margin: auto;
     width: 32%;">
    <img  style=" width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
     vertical-align: middle; " src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="Text" />
    <span>Howzaat</span>
</button>
<button style="   padding: 10px 16px 10px 16px;
     vertical-align: middle;  
     margin: auto;
     width: 32%;">
    <img  style=" width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
     vertical-align: middle; " src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="Text" />
    <span>Hurrey with the mission</span>
</button>
</div>
<div>
<button style="   padding: 10px 16px 10px 16px;
     vertical-align: middle;  
     margin: auto;
     width: 32%;">
    <img  style=" width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
     vertical-align: middle; " src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="Text" />
    <span>Stage</span>
</button>
<button style="   padding: 10px 16px 10px 16px;
     vertical-align: middle;  
     margin: auto;
     width: 32%;">
    <img  style=" width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
     vertical-align: middle; " src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="Text" />
    <span>catch me if you can</span>
</button>
<button style="   padding: 10px 16px 10px 16px;
     vertical-align: middle;  
     margin: auto;
     width: 32%;">
    <img  style=" width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
     vertical-align: middle; " src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="Text" />
    <span>jungle mission</span>
</button>
</div>
```

Above is the code am trying. here all images positions are moving here and there w.r.t text. But i need it to be fixed in one position in all buttons and make it identical. I need all images to be aligned in both rows and text as well.

Images position should be fixed and text starting position should be same in all buttons and should be middle of the button.

Some ref here.. here images are aligned and text should also be aligned

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rJ9h.png)

Comment: adding display flex, justify-content center and align-items center worked for me. https://gyazo.com/9b478b2d492560a7aef4598d7de1c9a8

Comment: I want Images to be alligned same position.. i mean 1st row image position and second row image position should be same irrespective of text

Comment: Added image as expected output ref .. updated in my question @Martin

Comment: Your image is literally the same as mine. If the sizes of the buttons is your issue, you can change them. Since they are 3 per row, you could have 1 main row wrapper and size each button to fit any width and gap layout you desire. Main row: dispaly flex, flex-direction row, flex-wrap wrap,  flex 0 0 100% (or whatever size you want your container to be), max-width (whatever maximum you want).

Comment: Can you post the answer please with snippet @Martin

Answer (score 0):

in button style, add the following styles

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Comment: Not worked @mouafus

Comment: is there enough space for both elements to fit on the same line?

Update your question with an image of the result

Comment: Already image also added.. i want all images to be alinged in same position and text aslo same .. if you see row1 3 buttons, row 2 3 buttons.. images are not in one line and text as well

Comment: Added expected output ref image in question

Comment: add justify-content: start;

Answer (score 0):

You could use flex to set up your desired grid (pick whichever sizing suits you, I set mine to 700px in width. If you delete the `btn-wrapper` class, it'll lose that property and go to 100% width.

You can mess around with how you want the image and text to be placed in the button by using `justify-content: center`, `justify-content: flex-start`, `justify-content: flex-end`, `justify-content: space-between`, `justify-content: space-evenly`, `justify-content: space-around`.

***View Snippet in full screen for best visualization!***

**Example as Snippet:**

```css
:root {
    --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
    --bs-gutter-y: 1.5rem;  
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
}

.row {
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: calc(var(--bs-gutter-y) * -1);
    margin-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * -.5);
    margin-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * -.5);
}

.row > * {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    margin-top: var(--bs-gutter-y);
}

.col-3 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 25%;
    max-width: 25%
}

.full-width {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #6c757d;
    border-color: #6c757d;
}

.btn-txt {
    color: #fff;
}

.img {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png");
}

.btn-wrapper {
 width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-wrapper flex row full-width wrap">
    <div class="flex col-3">
        <button class="btn">
            <img class="img" alt="Text" />
            <span class="btn-txt">Text for btn one</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container flex col-3">
        <button class="btn">
            <img class="img" alt="Text" />
            <span class="btn-txt">Text for btn two</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container flex col-3">
        <button class="btn">
            <img class="img" alt="Text" />
            <span class="btn-txt">Text for btn three</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container flex col-3">
        <button class="btn">
            <img class="img" alt="Text" />
            <span class="btn-txt">Text for btn four</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container flex col-3">
        <button class="btn">
            <img class="img" alt="Text" />
            <span class="btn-txt">Text for btn five</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container flex col-3">
        <button class="btn">
            <img class="img" alt="Text" />
            <span class="btn-txt">Text for btn six</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without flex is there a way? because my application doesn't support flex or inline-flex or flex-grow e.t.c

Comment: How on earth does your application not support that? Is it not a web app? Flex properties are pure CSS and supported in every browser.